# IE11: setting innerHtml does not set firstChild

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-11, innerhtml

I have a curious problem where a simple JSF page does not work under IE11. It works as expected under Firefox and Chrome but IE11 gives 'malformedXML: Illegal argument'.

Investigation with a debugger shows that the AJAX response from clicking on a radio button is being considered invalid by IE11 inside jsf.js.

The actual result is that Element.firstChild is set to null which I am assuming indicates that innerHtml content is not considered to be valid html. This happens on a) An Ajax response, and b) not on Firefox or Chrome

The relevant code in jsf.js is:

Line 1472: jsf.js version 2.2

```
         if (html.length > 0) {
                if (isAutoExec()) {
                    // Create html
                    parserElement.innerHTML = html;
                } else {
                    // Get the scripts from the text
                    scripts = stripScripts(html);
                    // Remove scripts from text
                    html = html.replace(/<script[^>]*type="text\/javascript"*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/igm,"");
                    parserElement.innerHTML = html;
                }
               replaceNode (parserElement.firstChild, d);
```

The AJAX response is:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes>
        <update id="payment:paymentgroup"><![CDATA[<span id="payment:paymentgroup">Enter <span id="payment:onaccount">Account</span></span>]]></update>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[-2818987988265526344:7981698299886652187]]></update>
        <extension id="org.richfaces.extension">
            <render>payment:paymentgroup</render>
        </extension>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

In the code above 'html' is set to:

```
<span id="payment:paymentgroup">Enter <span id="payment:onaccount">Account</span></span>
```

the result of 'parserElement.innerHTML = html' is that 'parserElement.firstChild' is left null giving rise to an exception in 'replaceNode (parserElement.firstChild, d)'

I have tried this html in a simple page containing similar javascript and it works. Presumably something in the environment/context is affecting it.

I would appreciate any guidance/advice how to solve or workaround this issue.

You can see the jsf code I am using below. A link to running code is

http://testshop.actionfarm.co.uk/actjsf/

I am using java 8.0.45, jboss 9.CR1 with Mojarra 2.2.10. I am also using Richfaces 4.5.4 although this is just JSF components.
(I was using jboss 8.2 but upgraded to see if it made a difference with a later Mojarra)

Comment: Please check if IE is by accident (different server, proxy, doctype etc) running in compatibility mode for the version hst is not working.